# How to select request date is between two dates for PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

Currently, I have two dates inside the database such as depart_date and return_date. For the view blade, the user must select the accident_date which is the accident_date must be between depart_date and return_date. So, before the the user submit the form, the form will check either the accident_date is exist between depart_date and return_date or not. I have created the sql command inside the controller. But, it gave me an error.

Error : syntax error, unexpected ''=>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Controller:

```
$startdate = InsuranceEnrollment::select('depart_date')
             ->where($request->accident_date '=>', 'depart_date') AND ($request->accident_date 
             '<=', 'return_date');

dd($startdate);
```

View blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label form-control-sm">Accident </label>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control date-picker" 
data-datepicker-color="primary" name="accident_date" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is not in proper way, here's how to do it.

```
 $startdate = InsuranceEnrollment::select('depart_date')->where([
     'depart_date' <= $request->accident_date,
     'return_date' => $request->accident_date,
 ])->get();
```

Comment: true, I have to use get()

Comment: sorry, I mislook it. :'( forgive me

Comment: @asad I'm sorry, but this condition is not correct, it's not between the two dates.

Comment: @Qonvex620 you need to fix the answer, no matter who be accepted, it's all right.

Comment: I don't know how to say. But, TsaiKoga answer also true when it's about the logic. However, Qonvex620 answer also true, when I need to use get. How to accept both answer? I feel guilty right now. Thanks anyway to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison condition need to be like this, so the `$request->accident_date` will between these two dates.

```
depart_date <= accident_date AND return_date >= accident_date
```

You need to use `WHERE ... AND...` like this:

```php
$startdate = InsuranceEnrollment::select('depart_date')
                                ->where('depart_date', '<=', $request->accident_date)
                                ->where('return_date', '>=', request->accident_date);
```